# MPRemoteCommandCenter is causing audio to play twice

Tags: ios, swift

I am using AVPlayer to play audio. I setup remote controls on viewDidLoad

```
let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.playCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.stopCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.isEnabled = true
        
        if #available(iOS 13, *){
            // Add handler for Play Command
            commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
                if self.isReadyToPlay, let player = self.audioPlayer, player.timeControlStatus != .playing  {
                    self.playCC()
                    return .success
                }
                return .commandFailed
            }
            
            // Add handler for Pause Command
            commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
                if self.isReadyToPlay, let player = self.audioPlayer, player.timeControlStatus == .playing  {
                    self.pauseCC()
                    return .success
                }
                return .commandFailed
            }
            
            
            commandCenter.stopCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
                self.pauseCC()
                return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
            }
            
            commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
                self.playPauseCC()
                return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
            }
            
            commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
                self.nextCC()
                return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
            }
            
            commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget { (event) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
                self.prevCC()
                return MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus.success
            }
            
        } else {
            commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pauseCC))
            commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playCC))
            commandCenter.stopCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.pauseCC))
            commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.playPauseCC))
            commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.nextCC))
            commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.prevCC))
        }
```

In ViewWillDisappear, I call

```
 let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
    commandCenter.playCommand.removeTarget(self)
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.removeTarget(self)
    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.removeTarget(self)
    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.removeTarget(self)
   
    if #available(iOS 9.1, *) {
        commandCenter.changePlaybackPositionCommand.removeTarget(self)
    }
```

unfortunately, there are times when I am playing the audio from the remote controls (the app is in the background), and the audio plays twice. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem, if you find something I really like to know. Thanks

Comment: are you found why? I have same problem

Comment: You might be having multiple instances of AVPlayer, and each one starts playing the the command is launched.